# Python Convert CSV to JSON function with correct data type

Tags: python, json, csv

I have a script that convert `CSV` to `Json` format using Python, but the Json output is all string (with "")

But some of the data is Integer, how can I define the column data type that I want to convert to?

Comment: Can you share the code you have so far and an example input and output?

Comment: And please provide an example of your CSV data - a few lines - which shows this problem when your code processes it. Also show the output.

Answer (score 1):

> Valid Data Types In JSON, values must be one of the following data types:
>   string, number, object (JSON object), an array, boolean and null.

```
Json output is all string (with "") ??
```

A json file example like this

```
{"widget": {
    "debug": "on",
    "window": {
        "title": "Sample Konfabulator Widget",
        "name": "main_window",
        "width": 500,
        "height": 500
    },
    "image": { 
        "src": "Images/Sun.png",
        "name": "sun1",
        "hOffset": 250,
        "vOffset": 250,
        "alignment": "center"
    },
    "text": {
        "data": "Click Here",
        "size": 36,
        "style": "bold",
        "name": "text1",
        "hOffset": 250,
        "vOffset": 100,
        "alignment": "center",
        "onMouseUp": "sun1.opacity = (sun1.opacity / 100) * 90;"
    }
}}
```

So don't care about your data is integer or string, just send the variable with your json content like this. json package will handle you data type issues for you.

```
import json

person_dict = {"name": "Bob",
               "languages": ["English", "Fench"],
               "married": True,
               "age": 32
              }

with open('person.txt', 'w') as json_file:
    json.dump(person_dict, json_file)
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood his question (although he was not quite verbose), what he means is values in your json example like hOffset are showing in his csv to json script like "hOffset": "250", that is integers and floats may be showing quoted as strings.